# Variable containing a path as a string to multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, path

I'm looking to take a string such as

```
"/test/uri/to/heaven"
```

and turn it into a multi-dimensional, nested array such as:

```
array(
    'var' => array(
        'www' => array(
            'vhosts' => array()            
        ),
    ),
);
```

Anyone got any pointers? I've had a look through Google and the search here, but I've not seen anything.

Comment: Doing this usually makes little sense, which is why there's no `explode()` function that works this way. What do you need this for?

Comment: Well, explode gives me a flat array. I was wondering how I get the results of an explode, retaining the depth of the path in the string as per my example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick non recursive hack:

```
$url   = "/test/uri/to/heaven";
$parts = explode('/',$url);

$arr = array();
while ($bottom = array_pop($parts)) {        
    $arr = array($bottom => $arr);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["uri"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["to"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["heaven"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my var_dump looks like this: array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["uri"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["to"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["heaven"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: i would like to be able to reverse this back to a string again. any idea how ?

Comment: @TarranJones this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array seems to be nice and short